# Why constructor is initialised to itself when inheriting

Tags: javascript

I found the following code for creating inheritance in Javascript in ES5. In this case, `Employee` is inheriting from `Person`.

```
function Employee(name, title) {
  Person.call(this, name); // super(name)
  this.title = title;
}
Employee.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype);
Employee.prototype.constructor = Employee;
Employee.prototype.describe = function() {
  return Person.prototype.describe.call(this) // super.describe()
         + ' (' +  this.title + ')';
};
```

I don't understand this line:

```
Employee.prototype.constructor = Employee;
```

So `Employee` is already defined on the first line. Why do we need to create a constructor for it and initialise it to itself? And how does this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not *creating* a constructor, just pointing the property `constructor` at the existing one. If you didn't, it would be misleading because the `constructor` property inherited by instances created using `new Employee` would be `Person`, not `Employee`:

```js
function Person() {
}
function Employee() {
    Person.call(this);
}
Employee.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype);

var per = new Person();
var emp = new Employee();
console.log(per.constructor === Person);   // true
console.log(emp.constructor === Employee); // false?
console.log(emp.constructor === Person);   // true?!?!!
```

Answer (score 0):

Object.create gives you a new object which is linked prototype of Person function. And once you have declared the prototype of Employee, you need to add link constructor property also, thats what is done on line

```
Employee.prototype.constructor = Employee;
```